# User matching query does not exist - django

Tags: django, django-views, django-users

I have a page which shows the user and their **about**. And in that, there's a link to update their **about**. But when I open that link it shows me with this error:

```
DoesNotExist at /profile/user/update_about/

User matching query does not exist.
```

And the traceback hightlights this line, which from the `profile` method in the views:

```
13.  user = User.objects.get(username=unquote(user_name))
```

However this error does not occur when I load the `profile` method. It occurs only on the `update_profile` method in the views.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from urllib import unquote

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from models import About
from forms import AboutForm
# Create your views here.


def profile(request, user_name):
    user = User.objects.get(username=unquote(user_name))
    about = About.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    about = about[0]

    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {
        'user':user,
        'about_user':about
    })

def update_about(request, user_name):
    user = User.objects.get(username=unquote(user_name))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AboutForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        about = About.objects.get(user=user)
        form = AboutForm(initial={'dob':about.dob})
        return render(request, 'update_about.html',{
            'form':form
        })
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'(?P<user_name>[\w@%.]+)/$', 'user_related.views.profile', name='profile'),
    url(r'(?P<user_name>[\w@%.]+)/update_about/$', 'user_related.views.update_about', name='update_about'),
```

What is causing this? Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In the url `/profile/user/update_about/`, _user_ is actual user name?

Comment: So it looks like there is no user with username "user" in your db.

Comment: It seems like your profile URL is catching the URL "user/update_about/", which it shouldn't. Are those the exact regexes you are using?

Comment: @Rohan No, there is. Infact the username of admin is *user*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. I just copied and pasted it here.

Comment: Can you try swapping the order of those URLs?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, that did the work! Thank you! Can I ask just one question please? Why did swapping the urls helped? And add your answer too.

Comment: Actually, catavaran has the answer: URLs are matched in order, and since you did not anchor your URLs at the start of the string, the "profile" urlpattern was matching the string "update_about" as a username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the caret sign (`^`) at the first position of regex.  So the first regex matched "update_about/" part of the url.

Fixed code:

```
url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w@%.]+)/$', 'user_related.views.profile', name='profile'),
url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w@%.]+)/update_about/$', 'user_related.views.update_about', name='update_about'),
```

Comment: This is not a routing problem because the view is found. There is something wrong with the user_name parameter.

Comment: Oh! now I see it, sorry.